# Combining CSV data frames

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse

I used this code to combine several csv files into one file at the beginning of my project around 5 months ago. I have now returned to re-sort my data in a different way. However, it now refuses to work simply returning an empty data set.

I am running R-Studio 4.2.0. Has there been an update to the console that has rendered my code useless?

my code:

```
# Initilise Libraries
library("magrittr")
library("dplyr")                                                  
library("readr")
library("tidyverse")
library("reticulate")
library("purrr")
library("data.table")
library("jsonlite")


# combine all data sets (CSV Files). This will Store all files in list

data_all <- list.files(path = "C:\\Users\\Surface\\Documents\\FinalProject\\Data\\Sky_Data\\csvData",    
                       pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  
  lapply(read_csv) %>%
  bind_rows
```

I then tried reading in one of the CSV files independently:

```
df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Surface\\Documents\\FinalProject\\Data\\Sky_Data\\csvData\\bookmaker-data-10-01.csv")
```

This now reads in the data from one file fine showing the files in question are in the specified folder.

Comment: Doubtful that there was a key change in functionality to`list.files`, `lapply`, or `bind_rows`. Are you confident that the files in the directory you're specifying actually have data? Are you receiving any other error messages when you run the script?

Comment: As a side note you're loading `magrittr`, `dplyr`, and `readr` which are all loaded as part of `tidyverse`. So that part of your code is redundant. The rest of the packages aren't used in the code you provided, but I guess those packages are used elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes those packages are later in the script. I have just tried to read one of the files in independently via read.csv and experienced a new error code. Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\Surface\Documents\FinalProject\Data\Sky_Data\bookmaker-data-10-01.csv': No such file or directory    However, the files are there because I can open them in excel

Comment: Can you import through RStudio Environment -> Import Dataset, either base or readr import? If yes, can you re-run the code generated by importer?

Comment: The error you are getting is a failure at the first step in opening a connection. Open Windows Explorer and paste `C:\Users\Surface\Documents\FinalProject\Data\Sky_Data\bookmaker-data-10-01.csv` and hit enter - that will absolutely confirm the file and path is correct.

Comment: I recognised that I had missed out a folder on the single read-in. this now works fine. Just having problems with listing and combining all of the csv files with the lapply function

Comment: Well, that importing pattern works on my machine(tm) (W10/R4.2/up to date tidyverse).  But you don't really need bind_rows nor lapply here: `readr::read_csv()` file parameter can also be a vector of filenames, so you can just pipe in the list.files() and it combines all csv-files into single tibble.  `data_all <- list.files(path = "./tmp_r/", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% read_csv()`

Comment: It has absolutely stumped me. I tried to do it using the vroom function and the do.call function too but got different types of errors.  It is definitely a connection problem

Comment: sidenote: `pattern = "*.csv"` might not work as you intended.. the dot is a special regex-operator, that means "any character". So a file like `thisisnotacsv.txt` will match your regex (`acsv` will match the regex). If you want a literal dot, you have to escape it.. if only you want files with the .csv-extention, add an end-character.. like: `".*\\.csv$"`.

Comment: Wimpel That solved the problem!

Comment: @wimpel if you submit it as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, the problem seemed to be the (common!) mistake that *.csv selects all csv-files in a folder. it does not..

The dot `.` (and the `*` for that matter) are special regex-operators, where the `.` means "any character". So a file like thisisnotacsv.txt will match the regex `*.csv` (acsv will match the regex). If you want a literal dot, you have to escape it.. if only you want files with the .csv-extention, add an end-character.. like: `.*\\.csv$`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting around this error using the following code

```
path <- "C:\\Users\\Surface\\Documents\\FinalProject\\Data\\Sky_Data\\csvData"

multmerge = function(path){
  filenames=list.files(path=path, full.names=TRUE)
  rbindlist(lapply(filenames, fread))
}

alldata <- multmerge(path)
```

However I am still not sure on what the initial problem was